# RUBY: How to match a nil value in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, null

I would like to ask you how can I match a nil value in a hash, e. g.:

```
aAnimals = {1=>'dog', 2=>'cat'}
puts laAnimals[1]  # dog
puts laAnimals[2]  # cat
puts laAnimals[3]  # nil
```

how can I put 'no animal' in case of nil values or higher than lenght of the matrix, e.g.:

```
laAnimals = {1=>'dog', 2=>'cat'}
laAnimals.default = 'no animal'

puts laAnimals[1]  # dog
puts laAnimals[2]  # cat
puts laAnimals[3]  # no animal
```

I want something like that: `laAnimals = {1=>'dog', 2=>'cat', default='no animal'}`...it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exupery's answer is correct, but if you don't have access to the creation of the hash you're working with, you can use `Hash#fetch` ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)).

```
laAnimals = {1=>'dog', 2=>'cat'}
puts laAnimals.fetch(1, 'no animal')  # dog
puts laAnimals.fetch(2, 'no animal')  # cat
puts laAnimals.fetch(3, 'no animal')  # 'no animal'
```

I personally prefer this way of accessing hashes, because if the key (in your example, `1`, and `2`) is not present it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 3):

From http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html

> Hashes have a default value that is returned when accessing keys that
>   do not exist in the hash. If no default is set nil is used. You can
>   set the default value by sending it as an argument to ::new:

So in your case using `laAnimals = Hash.new("no animal")` will use the string `no animal` as the default value.